# React "TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined" when inside "Map"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, material-ui

As you can see below. The first photo works fine when

```
this.state.blabal
```

is NOT inside the

```
map(a, b){blabla}
```

but like as photo2, when i move the working-fine block inside the

```
map(a, b){`here!!`}

 {Object.keys(newsProviderID_Name_Dic).map(function(key, index){
                    return<FormControlLabel
                        control={
                            <Switch
                                checked={this.state.gilad}
                                onChange={this.handleChange('gilad')}
                                value="gilad"
                            />
                        }
                        label="Gilad Gray"
                    />;
                })}
```

It will show up the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Why is this happening? and how to solve this without binding individually?

[image: this works fine]
[image: this causes the error]
[image: the error message]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use an arrow function

```
Object.keys(newsProviderID_Name_Dic).map((key, index) => {
                return () } )
```

inside an arrow function, `this` maintains the same meaning as the enclosing scope

Answer (score 1):

May be you not set initial state for Component.
you try it :

```
class Example extends Component {
   state:{}
   render(){
   //.....code
  }
}
```

or

```
class Example extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      this.state={};
    }
```

}

Good luck!

Comment: While it's a good idea to always have an initial state it's not the reason for the problem here. You can see from the error message that `this` is already `undefined` because the callback for the `map()` function is not bound to the component instance.